# Redux toolkit inside ts file - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux toolkit inside the `ts` file and it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

index.js?46cb:334 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (/.../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at useReduxContext (/.../node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useReduxContext.js:27:44)
    at useStore (/.../node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useStore.js:28:28)
    at useDispatch (/.../node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useDispatch.js:24:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./mytsfile.ts:33:14)
    at Object../mytsfile.ts (/.../.next/server/pages/index.js:25:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (/.../.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///.mytsfile.tsx:33:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (/.../.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
```

my code:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { actionFromSlice } from "../../actionss.ts";

...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(actionFromSlice('a'));
...
```

Comment: Did you wrap your App in the redux Provider?

Comment: Yes. I did. All other parts of the app using that way just file. But they are inside `.tsx` file. Now, i'm facing that error inside `.ts` file.

Comment: There is not enough info to help you debug this. But you can try to delete your `node_modules` and reinstall your dependencies, just in case.